# Did Southwest airlines retire flight 1380 following the accident, and with what number?

Tags: accidents

Just wondering if Southwest Airlines flight 1380 was retired and replaced with a different flight number following [the uncontained engine failure and depressurization accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwest_Airlines_Flight_1380) in April 2018?

Answer (score 2):

[According to FlightAware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/SWA1380/history/80), Southwest has not operated a flight with flight number 1380 since [the accident flight](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/SWA1380/history/20180417/1430Z/KLGA/KDAL) on April 17. The flights with that number for several weeks after the accident were all been marked as cancelled in the FlightAware database; other flight numbers were used:

[image]

Southwest uses the same flight number for many flight segments in a day, but their [flight schedule](https://www.southwest.com/air/flight-schedules/results.html?departureDate=2018-07-15&destinationAirportCode=DAL&originationAirportCode=LGA&scheduleViewType=weekly&timeOfDay=ALL_DAY) shows that flights from LGA to DAL leaving at around 10:30am are using the flight numbers 5227 (Sundays, 10:35) and 237 (weekdays, 10:45).

Answer (score 0):

It appears so, as there is [no longer a flight 1380 from LGA to DAL](https://www.southwest.com/air/booking/select.html?adultPassengersCount=1&departureDate=2018-07-03&departureTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&destinationAirportCode=DAL&fareType=USD&leapfrogRequest=true&originationAirportCode=LGA&passengerType=ADULT&redirectToVision=true&returnDate=2018-07-07&returnTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&seniorPassengersCount=0&tripType=roundtrip).